# Object Origin needs reset for animation

Tags: keyframes, origin

I forgot to set an object's origin to **'center of mass'** before adding animation to the scene and object.

I now need to rotate the object around its center, but due to the incorrect origin, the rotation is not centered. Centering the origin now results in the object's position changing due to the existing key frames.

Generally in scenarios like this, I'd either remove all key frames from the object - set the correct origin - and 'fit the animation back into the scene, or just delete and re-import.

Curious to know if there is an easier workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an empty where you want your pivot point, set it as parent of your object and rotate the empty.

Comment: But all location keyframes are then relative to the empty's origin, which results in the same or similar problem as if he changed the object's origin. Or at least if I understood the question correctly that he wants to animate the rotation as well.

Comment: Yes!!! Perfect - Thanks Josh